# mongoDB upsert on array

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

my db model looks like this

```
"clientId":"123456"
"devices" : 
[{
      "deviceId" : "123",
      "deviceType" : "ios",
      "notification" : true,
  }
  {
      "deviceId" : "321",
      "deviceType" : "android",
      "notification" : true,

  }
 ]
```

The c# model I pass to my DB method has ClientId,DeviceId,DeviceType,notification. Note that it doesn't have an array of devices

the behaviour I'm trying to achieve

1. (working) If ClientId is not yet in the database, create a new record in db with the passed value,(devices array will have one element)
2. If ClientId is already found in the database, update the the record according to the following rules:

   2.1 If devices array doesn't contain DeviceId add a new element to the array with the passed values

   2.2 If devices array already contains DeviceId update the element's deviceType and notification.

I'm using c#. any help appreciated

example: given the above state of database, by passing clientId: 123456, deviceId 321 deviceType "kindle", notification "false" the db will change to

```
"clientId":"123456"
"devices" : 
[{
      "deviceId" : "123",
      "deviceType" : "ios",
      "notification" : true,
  }
  {
      "deviceId" : "321",
      "deviceType" : "kindle",
      "notification" : false,

  }
 ]
```

Comment: Good question. Raise a JIRA. Can I add something to you question to clarify the problem?

Comment: did you delete your update? I didn't understand so well what you were saying and now it's gone..

Comment: Yes, because I thought it actually warranted another question. I asked the specific case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667183/update-with-setoninsert-and-set-in-combination-failing)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not really as simple as you might think, and actually it is interesting that you have broken your analysis of this into three parts. Because, guess what? That is exactly what you **must** do. Let's consider the steps:

### 1. Insert a document if one doesn't exist

```js
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "clientId":"123456"
    },
    {
        "$setOnInsert": {
            "clientId": "123456",
            "devices": [{
                "deviceId": "321",
                "deviceType" : "kindle",
                "notification" : false
            }]
        }
    },
    { "upsert": true }
)
```

So what you want to do is **insert** a new document where the "clientId" currently does not exist. This can be done as an "upsert" to avoid possible unique key clashes and even where there is no "unique" constraint, then the "upsert" nature of this ensures you only create the "new" document when it was not found. Also there is `$setOnInsert` here because you **do not** want to do anything to a document that is "found" at this point.

Note here that there is **no** attempt to match the element in the array. This is because you likely do not want to "create" a new document just because an existing one did not have "that" array element. Which brings us to the next step.

### 2. Update the contents of the document where it does exist

```js
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "clientId":"123456",
        "devices": { "$elemMatch": { "deviceId" : "321" } }
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "devices.$.deviceType" : "kindle",
            "devices.$.notification" : false
        }
    }
)
```

Now here you want to actually try and "match" the document for the "clientId" that **does** contain an element in the array that also matches the "deviceId" you are looking for. So by specifying a condition to match, you get the use of the positional `$` operator in order to set the fields in the "matching" position.

As above, this was either going to match **one** thing or **nothing** so either the update was done or it wasn't. So that moves to our final part of the cascade here:

### 3. Add the array element where it does not exist

```js
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "clientId":"123456"
    },
    {
        "$addToset": { "devices": {
            "deviceId" : "321",
            "deviceType" : "kindle",
            "notification" : false
        }}
    }
)
```

So this is **importantly** the last stage. The reason being that if either of the preceding operations **did** "create" or "update" the existing document, then the use of `$addToSet` here makes **sure** you are not "pushing" another document to the array with the same "deviceId" but other different values. If **one** of those stages worked, then this would see all the values of that element to already exist, and would not then add another one.

If you tried to do that in a different order, in the case you present you would have **two** documents in the array with the same "deviceId", but differing values for "deviceType" and "notification". So that is why it comes last.

### Conclusion

So unfortunately, there is no simple way to combine these as **one** operation. The operators simply do not exist so that this could be done in a single statement and therefore you **must** perform **three** update operations in order to do what you want. Also as stated, the **order** of application for those updates is **important** so that you get the desired result.

While this does not exist yet in current "production" releases, the upcoming release ( 2.6 and upwards as of writing) does have a way to to ["batch"](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/update/#bulk-update) these requests with an new syntax to [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/update/):

```js
db.runCommand(
    "update": "collection",
    "updates": [
        { 
            "q": { "clientId":"123456" },
            "u": {
                "$setOnInsert": {
                    "clientId": "123456",
                    "devices": [{
                    "deviceId": "321",
                    "deviceType" : "kindle",
                    "notification" : false
                }]
            },
            "upsert": true
        },
        {
            "q": { 
                 "clientId":"123456",
                 "devices": { "$elemMatch": { "deviceId" : "321" } }
            },
            "u": {
                "$set": {
                    "devices.$.deviceType" : "kindle",
                    "devices.$.notification" : false
                 }
            }
        },
        {
            "q": { "clientId":"123456" },
            "u": {
                "$addToset": { "devices": {
                    "deviceId" : "321",
                    "deviceType" : "kindle",
                    "notification" : false
                }}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

So while that is *still* essentially three operations, at least you get to send them *over the wire* just once

Comment: wow, what a detailed and structured response. Thank you for taking the time to write this!

Comment: So, asking because it was one of the labels on the OP, but do you by chance know how to achieve this using the C# driver?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a typical positional operator case:

```
db.coll.update
(
    {
        "clientId":"123456","devices.deviceId":"321"
    },
    {
        $set:
        {
            "devices.$.deviceType":"kindle","devices.$.notification":"false"
        }
    }
)
```

You need to update an element matched inside an array, $ does this for you, so you can find a document with a specific element inside of an array and "remember" with the positional operator $ which one you matched to update it.

Comment: thanks. this updates it properly if it already contains the deviceId, is there a way to generalize it to insert a new element if the element doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not in this case due to the positional operator is a very specific case and upsert won't work, due to it's an array. I've been thinking there could be a trick with pop and push but it's too complicated. I would check if upsert updated a record, in case it didn't I would do an insert, instead of searching records always (at least you reduce a percentage the operations)